# Gtk.TextView very slow with many TextTags

Tags: python, performance, gtk, gtk3

I need to continually change the styling of parts of a `TextView` to do syntax highlighting. However with about 1,000 `Gtk.TextTags` it becomes extremely slow. I don't want to use a `Gtk.SourceView` because I want to customize styling myself. It seems rather odd that 1,000 tags is enough to make the `TextView` choppy since a word processing document might have that many.

This code gives an example of the slowness. With 1,000s of characters it starts taking about half a second to update the tags.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_default_size(600, 400)

        self.scrolledwindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.textview = Gtk.TextView()

        buffer = self.textview.get_buffer()
        buffer.create_tag("tag", background="orange")
        buffer.connect("end-user-action", self.action)

        self.scrolledwindow.add(self.textview)
        self.add(self.scrolledwindow)

    def action(self, buffer):
        start = buffer.get_start_iter()
        veryend = buffer.get_end_iter()
        buffer.remove_all_tags(start, veryend)
        end = buffer.get_iter_at_offset(1)

        for i in range(len(buffer.get_text(start, veryend, False))//2+1):
            buffer.apply_tag_by_name("tag", start, end)
            start.forward_chars(2)
            end.forward_chars(2)

win = MyWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Can I speed this up? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, but I would be surprised if there was styling customization that you couldn't do with GtkSourceView.

Answer (score 1):

If someone ever finds this question via google let me tell you that the problem here is the removing of all tags and adding it again. This is of course a very time consuming operation and shouldn't be coded this way.